# Adding new namespace location to composer psr-4

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I am trying to figure out what to do about adding a new location to the psr-4 in Composer.

```
    "psr-4" : {
        "OpenEMR\\Common\\" : "common",
        "OpenEMR\\Entities\\" : "entities",
        "OpenEMR\\Rx\\Weno\\" : "library/weno/src",
        "OpenEMR\\Staff\\" : "library/staff/src"
    }
```

The staff folder is what I am adding. My question is do I need to run the composer update for this to be added to the autoloader?

I have tried running composer update and it seems to update all the dependency packages. I don't want that. All I need it to do is add the last line to the namespace system.

I have searched the web but the information that I have seen don't seem to answer my question. I can't find a clear answer to adding a new namespace via composer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to run:

`composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 0):

Anything that will generate autoloader files will be enough - running `composer dump-autoload` or `composer install` will include new settings to project's autoloader.

There is also `--lock` switch for [`update`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update-u) command, which will update `composer.lock` without actually upgrading any package.

```
composer update --lock
```